# How to scale and translate rect widget depend on some InteractiveViewer?

Tags: flutter

I Paint a bitmap and wrap it in a InteractiveViewer.
And it can be scaled and translated well.

Now I want to put a rect or sticker view on it,
how to scale it or translate it with the interactiveViewer?

Thanks!

/**/
edit:
I had try to add the rect widget to the InteractiveViewer.
But It will produce the other problem like the issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72978

So I try a new one:
I make the rect with containers, and detect the gesture callback.
Put the rect outside the InteractiveViewer.
When I drag the rect corner. I can resize the rect.
But now I scaled the interactiveViewer, the rect won't scaled together.

```
child: InteractiveViewer(
                        key: _targetKey,
                        boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 512,
                          vertical: 512,
                        ),
                        minScale: 0.5,
                        maxScale: 10,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
CustomPaint(
                                          foregroundPainter:
                                              WaterRipplePainter(
                                                  _controllerRipple.value,
                                                  provider.item4,
                                                  originPoint),
                                          painter: ImagePainter(
                                            provider.item1,
                                            provider.item2,
                                            provider.item3,
                                          ),
                                        );
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
// The Rect is use Containers with other 9 corner balls
stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top: top,
      left: left,
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        color: Colors.red[100],
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    ),
    // top left
    Positioned(
      top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
      left: left - ballDiameter / 2,
      child: ManipulatingBall(
        onDrag: (dx, dy) {
          var mid = (dx + dy) / 2;
          var newHeight = height - 2 * mid;
          var newWidth = width - 2 * mid;

          setState(() {
            height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
            width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
            top = top + mid;
            left = left + mid;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    // top middle
    Positioned(
      top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
      left: left + width / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
      child: ManipulatingBall(
        onDrag: (dx, dy) {
          var newHeight = height - dy;

          setState(() {
            height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
            top = top + dy;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    // top right
    Positioned(
```

[image]

Comment: if your `CustomPaint` is a child of `InteractiveViewer` you dont have to do anything as `InteractiveViewer` do that for you, or maybe i am missing something?

Comment: The Rect is not draw by CustomPaint. I add the code for the Rect. Can I scale the interactiveViewer of the Map, then the Rect is scaled with it?